# Having problem keeping user signed in after publising to host

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, cookies, asp.net-core-2.1

After I publish my code in local iis cookie stay alive for 1 month as configured in code
but after publishing it in host , cookie only stays alive for 20 minutes.
**I am using a shared host.**
This is how i configured cookie :

```
services.AddAuthentication()
              .AddCookie(cookieSettings.MemberCookieScheme, options =>
              {
                  options.Cookie.Name = cookieSettings.MemberCookieScheme;
                  options.LoginPath = "/Profile/Login";
                  options.LogoutPath = "/Profile/Logout";
                  options.SlidingExpiration = true; 
                  options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(30);
                  options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromDays(30);
              });
```

And this code to sign in users :

```
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(_siteSettings.CookieSettings.MemberCookieScheme, principalMember,
                new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = true });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found an answer.
I created a `BackgroundService` which has a timer in it and every 10 minutes it makes a request to my url address to extend the session timeout.

```
 public class ExtendLoginHostedService : IHostedService, IDisposable
    {
        private Timer _timer;        
        private readonly ILogger<ExtendLoginHostedService> _logger;

        public ExtendLoginHostedService(ILogger<ExtendLoginHostedService> logger)
        {
            this._logger = logger;
        }

        public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("ExtendLogin Hosted Service running.");

            _timer = new System.Threading.Timer(async (ev) =>
            {
                DoWorkAsync(stoppingToken);

            }, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private void DoWorkAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                using (Stream stream = client.OpenRead("https://your-site.com"))
                {
                    // This part is just for making sure that currect data has received or not
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("ExtendLogin Hosted Service is stopping.");

            _timer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _timer?.Dispose();
        }
```

And register it at `StartUp` class:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{        
     services.AddHostedService<ExtendLoginHostedService>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with shared host.

By default the idle timeout in IIS is 20 minutes.

1. If you have access to the server, you need to increase or turn off
   the Idle Timeout in Application Pool in IIS.
2. If you do not have access to the Web Server, you can create a new
   Endpoint in your program called HeartBeat or HealthCheck and within
   20 minutes, call this API to prevent Terminate.

Search for these :

- Prevent IIS idle timeout termination.
- Call Health Check Automatically ASP.NET Core